# Create a NuGet package while offline

Tags: nuget, package, offline

I want to create a NuGet package from a machine that is on the office intranet, but blocks all connections to the internet.

Both NuGetPackageExplorer.application and NuGet.exe will show the exception that "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

Installing packages works fine as we have a local network folder with the .nupkg packages we use.

Is there a tool I can use to create a NuGet package on that machine?

**Update**:
I created a issue on codeplex for this:  https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3196

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is downloading [the source code from CodePlex](http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest), going into the CommandLine project, deleting UpdateCommand.cs, and rebuilding the project.  I then grabbing the exe which I renamed NuGetOffline.exe and put it along with NuGet.Core.dll to somewhere in the Path.

**Update**

The [download page for NuGet](https://nuget.codeplex.com/releases) does not have the current version of NuGet.exe.  As of writing this, none of the three downloads on the page work offline and the Other Downloads have several version of Nuget.Tools, but not the current version of NuGet.exe.  Go [here](https://nuget.org/nuget.exe) instead for nuget.exe.  Use that instead of that custom build.

The Package Explorer link on the download page is just the ClickOnce installer which does work offline.  You need to find the local executable [here](https://npe.codeplex.com/releases).

I haven't been able to get "Enable NuGet Package Restore" to work on the intranet.  [This closed work item](https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2390) describes the problem.  The last comment says that "2.0 should no longer run into this issue", but I am using NuGet Package Manager 2.2.400116.9051.